# How to design to prompt users for new values for properties of deserialized objects?

Tags: c#, serialization

Right now, I'm currently serializing a class like this:

```
class Session
{
     String setting1;
     String setting2;
     ...etc... (other member variables)

     List<SessionAction> actionsPerformed;
}
```

Where SessionAction is an interface that just has one method.  All implementations of the SessionAction interface have various properties describing what that specific SessionAction does.

Currently, I serialize this to a file which can be loaded again using the default .Net binary serializer.  Now, I want to serialize this to a *template*.  This template will just be the List of SessionActions serialized to a file, but upon loading it back into memory at another time, I want some properties of these SessionActions to require input from the user (which I plan to dynamically generate GUI controls on the fly depending on the property type).  Right now, I'm stuck on determining the best way to do this.

Is there some way I could flag some properties so that upon using reflection, I could determine which properties need input from user?  Or what are my other options?  Feel free to leave comments if anything isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For info, I don't recommend using `BinaryFormatter` for anything that you are storing long-term; it is very [brittle between versions](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/obfuscation-serialization-and.html). It is fine for short-lived messages where you know the same version will be used for serialization and deserialization.

I would recommend any of: `XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer` (3.0), or for fast binary, [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/); all of these are contract-based, so much more version tolerant.

Re the question; you could use things like `Nullable<T>` for value-types, and `null` for strings etc - and ask for input for those that are null? There are other routes involving things like the `ShouldSerialize*` pattern, but this might upset the serialization APIs.

Comment: So I guess with the nullable types, I'd have to override the serialize method for whatever serialization method I use?  If I do this, how would I support two forms of serialization (one would have all the properties and the other would only have a couple)?

Comment: To be honest, I'd probably have different request DTOs for the different bunches of required parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you know from start what properties will have that SessionAction, you must implement IDeserializationCallback and put to those props the attribute [NonSerialized]. When you implement the OnDeserialization method you get the new values from the user.